# Catch and eat an exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, log4net, logging

I have the following code that throws

```
try
{
    fileInfo.CopyTo(destination, true);
}
catch (IOException ioex)
{

}
```

Log4net log :

```
35552|384|1|ERROR| at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

I need to eat this exception and **not** log it. I need to supress this error message.

How to do that?

Comment: don't call log.Error inside your catch?

Comment: @David: My guess is he's working on a codebase that logs unhandled exceptions, and that he doesn't have control over the unhandled exception handler.

Comment: @Harpo that would greatly reduce the likelihood of the exception happening, but for IO stuff you still need to catch and handle the exception appropriately because there's no guarantee that between the time you check and the time the IO operation is performed, some external program has not modified the disk such that the operation is no longer valid. (And... it looks like the comment I was replying to was deleted...)

Comment: I'd fail that in a code review all day long.  Hidden exceptions are my #1 no-no.

Comment: @user I think this is specific to log4net and you might have more luck tagging and naming it as such.  Maybe also look at Log4net's documentation about having exceptions to logging exceptions.

Comment: @Greg: Presumably the OP is doing some copy operation that throws exceptions so frequently that he doesn't even want it logged. How do you suggest he handle this situation?

Comment: @Gabe: I've never had to write highly performant code that constantly throws exception, so I don't know. I'd try to figure out why it was throwing so many exceptions.  If it's in a tight loop, I'd at least try to log the first occurrence of the exception.

Comment: @Greg: In this case, the OP is trying to copy a file. Pretend he's trying to keep a local file lazily synchronized with a networked file. He tries to copy the file once per minute. On 10-20% of times the file is in use so the copying fails, but it doesn't matter because the operation will start again in a minute. At this rate he would get hundreds of log messages per day saying that the file is in use! Even logging the first message is pointless.

Comment: @Gabe: Well, I still don't like it.  I'd need someone to prove to me that an important exception (like a hardware failure or something) wasn't lost in the shuffle.

Comment: @Greg: Remember, each useless log message makes it harder to find actual error messages, makes it more likely that log files will wrap around (deleting actual errors), and in pathological cases makes it possible to fill up the hard drive and cause the whole system to fail. If they cause customer support calls, they could actually cost you a lot of time and money.

Comment: @Gabe: Well, you've basically convinced me, but I'd still probably log it to a database instead of a flat file.

Comment: @Platinum Azure But there isn't any unhandled exception in the code shown. (Assuming that fileInfo.CopyTo() is actually the CopyTo() Method on System.IO.FileInfo and not some custom code that happens to have the same name and does something inside which we cannot see).

Comment: @Platinum Azure Sorry, forget that last comment. I just found out that the question was edited and apperantly didn't sport a try/catch-block initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you'll need to look at Log4net to see if there's a way to either only log unhandled exceptions (if that's what's desired) or a way to tell it to ignore an exception in a specific place.

Why specifically do you want to hide this though?  If it's because this happens a lot and fills up the log with useless info then you may want to do some validation before calling `CopyTo` to make sure there's a reasonable chance it'll succeed (i.e. path is valid, file exists, etc).  This will also cut down on the number of exceptions throw in the first place.  Exceptions are somewhat expensive performance-wise so you'll want to prevent them from occuring if you can.

As I mentioned in a comment on the question, you can't remove the exception handling entirely because there's always a chance another program deleted the file in between checking it's existing and actually calling `CopyTo`, but it should be an extremely rare occurrence.

If this isn't happening frequently and/or you're already doing checks, what harm is there in having this occasionally logged?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Put the function call in a try/catch, catch the exception in question, and supply an empty block:</s>

```
try
{
    fileInfo.CopyTo(destination, true);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Note that catching Exception (rather than the proper subclass) is TERRIBLE practice.

Okay, the question was edited stealthily as I wrote this. I have no clue about log4net logging all exceptions that pass through the CLR at all. I'll be deleting this shortly, but for now I'm leaving it up in case of further comment.

Comment: How is this a better solution than the code the OP originally posted?  He should stick to swallowing a specific exception, just make sure it is the right one(s) (and that its ignorable in all circumstances which is tough to prove).  There may be something specific about Log4net that logs all thrown exceptions in which case he should consult the documentation or wait for an answerer who is familiar with Log4net.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Oh no fair. He edited the question! In that case I'm apparently not familiar enough with log4net. I didn't know you could intercept exception catches. It strikes me as a terrible practice-- what if some poorly-designed library uses exceptions to signal failure conditions? The logs would be completely polluted with exceptions that are likely eaten!

Comment: my thinking was that, since this is not an exception but an Error. as it says. is it possible to eat the errors?

Comment: How about trying to troubleshoot the error? What's the error? Do you get a chance to spot the error code at all? That could tell us a lot.

Comment: [UPDATES MAKE MY ORIGINAL COMMENT IRRELEVANT]

Comment: the error is legitimate. file is not found. and it s fine. i dont want to see the error. i dont care about it. error is just blowing the logs.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: No worries. The question originally didn't feature a try-catch block at all and I didn't know what the exception was. @user177883: You might consider using a function that checks if the file exists first, before invoking the `CopyTo` method. Then you can avoid triggering an exception in the first place.